# Apache Tomcat Server not showing properly, just listing files

Tags: tomcat8

my Apache Tomcat server on browser did not show the typical server management page, instead, it is showing the file directory. Could anyone advise what might be wrong?
[image]

Comment: Normally the manager is at `/manager`.  Your `webapps/ROOT` directory is missing `index.jsp` so you can't display the default webapp.  Additionally, these files are 6 years old - what version of Tomcat are you running?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am using Tomcat 8.5.6. I will reinstall Tomcat then.